# Java: Child Node values are null

Tags: java, xml

My xml (created by calling a Powershell command through Java):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<Objects>
    -<Object>
        <Property Name="DisplayName">Adobe AIR</Property>
        <Property Name="DisplayVersion">27.0.0.124</Property>
        <Property Name="Publisher">Adobe Systems Incorporated</Property>
        <Property Name="InstallDate"/>
    </Object>
```

I am trying to the DisplayName, DisplayVersion and Publisher values into variables, but am getting nulls and #text values returned by:

```
try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dBF = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dB = dBF.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dB.parse(new File(filename));

        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Object");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);

            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element e = (Element)node;
                System.out.println("Node " + count.toString());

                NodeList childNodeList = e.getChildNodes();
                for (int j = 0; j < childNodeList.getLength() ; j++) {
                    Node childNode = childNodeList.item(j);
                    System.out.print("Child Node Type: " + childNode.getNodeType() + " - ");
                    System.out.print("Child Element Name: " + childNode.getNodeName() + " - ");
                    System.out.println("Element Value: " + childNode.getNodeValue());
                }
                count++;    

            }
        }
```

This code returns this output for all 123 nodes that exist in my XML file:

```
Node 0
Child Node Type: 3 - Child Element Name: #text - Element Value: 

Child Node Type: 1 - Child Element Name: Property - Element Value: null
Child Node Type: 3 - Child Element Name: #text - Element Value: 

Child Node Type: 1 - Child Element Name: Property - Element Value: null
Child Node Type: 3 - Child Element Name: #text - Element Value: 

Child Node Type: 1 - Child Element Name: Property - Element Value: null
Child Node Type: 3 - Child Element Name: #text - Element Value: 

Child Node Type: 1 - Child Element Name: Property - Element Value: null
Child Node Type: 3 - Child Element Name: #text - Element Value:
```

I've been searching high and low for examples of how to read an XML file with content formatted like mine and am really struggling with my very limited Java knowledge.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not go deep enough.

You are displaying only the child nodes themselves, and the whitespace text nodes in between them, without actually looking at the text nodes inside the child nodes -- i.e. the actual text nodes you are interested in.

In your inner loop, for each element node you must retrieve that node's child nodes, among which you will find the text you are seeking

```
            for (int j = 0; j < childNodeList.getLength() ; j++) {
                Node childNode = childNodeList.item(j);
                NodeList subList = childNode.getChildNodes();
                for (int k = 0; k<subList.getLength(); k++)
                {
                     etc...
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you, Jim Garrison!  Whilst my subNode Names are still '#text', the values are flowing though and that's all I need to progress past this.

Comment: Text nodes will _always_ be named `#text`, that's the way the DOM works.  Look at the table near the top of [org.w3c.dom.Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) to see what the names and values of the different node types are.

Comment: How then to identify the subNode name?  For example, know the value I am retrieving relates ti DisplayName?  If I try to use getAttributes(),  [i.e. System.out.println("Name: " + subNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("DisplayName").getNodeName() + " - ");] I get a runtime error (NullPointerException).

Comment: In your example there will be 4 nodes named `Property`. Each node will have an attribute named `Name`, and a child node named `#text`.  Use the `Name` attribute to know which specific `Property` you are looking at.

Comment: Perhaps I should start a new question, but then I should be able to retrieve the name of that Attribute with: NamedNodeMap subMap = subNode.getAttributes();
                            Node subMapNode = subMap.getNamedItem("Name");
                            System.out.println("Name: " + subMapNode.getNodeName() + " - ");  which gives me a NullPointerException error

Comment: First go read the Javadoc carefully.  Then write some minimal test code, and step through one line at a time, making sure you are doing what you think you are doing.  If you still can't figure it out ask a new question, but avoid using the phrase "I get a NullPointerException" as that will get closed as a dup.  Ask instead something like "why does `getNodeName()` return null in this situation".  I suspect you are using the wrong method or your expectation does not match the JavaDoc.